# How to reconfigure windows+shift+s key combinations to open different app instead of screen-snip app?

Tags: windows, screenshot

I recently found a screenshot app inside a Windows PE iso. It's ScreenshotCentStudio.exe and size is just few KB.

[image]

The small app is fast and more responsive than inbuild windows screenshot capture apps. So how can I replace windows+shift+s from opening "screen snip" to "ScreenshotCentStudio" app?
Additionally, please let me know if anyone found the developers website.

Heads-up information:

- I'm new to tweaks, kinda noob.
- I have tried some softwares like AutoHotKey and Clavier+ but can't replace the screen-snip app with ScreenshotCentStudio.
- OS : Windows 11

Comment: Have you tried the obvious: AutoHotKey (https://www.autohotkey.com/), Clavier+ (https://gryder.org/software/clavier-plus/) or similar app to steal that key combo? Please put that in your question, rather than as a comment.

Comment: Thats fine, but is there anything which I can do with regedit like not needing additional software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in key-mapping function of Windows can only do key-replacements,
but not key-combinations. You need other software for that.

The Microsoft software for remapping key-combinations also
cannot run programs, as described for the
[PowerToys Keyboard Manager utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager).

You really need AutoHotKey (or its equivalents) for this task.

The AutoHotKey script for this problem should be pretty simple :

```
+#s::Run, C:\path\ScreenshotCentStudio.exe
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your help, and this stupid stackexchange for deleting the comments.

Answer (score 1):

First you want to disable the screen snipping tool entirely. This can only be done through regedit or group policy. Try group policy first:

Open the Group Policy Editor.

Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Tablet PC > Accessories.

Double-click Do not allow Snipping Tool to run.

Click on Enabled.

Reboot your computer and now CRTL+SHIFT+S should no longer call the built-in Windows Snipping Tool.

Proceed to map your shortcut to your desired application. You might to take a look at Microsoft Powertoys instead of Autohotkey because it has keyboard shortcut mapping functionality.

Comment: Thank you. it worked. Any idea how to disable win+s to stop opening start menu?